# JavaScript Username/Password Code Does Not Work

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a website code for something and make a username and password. I do't know if this is completely logical or if the code would work even if it was fixed, but I am a beginner and I am working from nothing. Here is what I have:

```html
<script>
alert("Welcome. Please click ok and enter your username.")
</script>
<script>
var userName=prompt("Please enter your username:","Username")
if(userName="person") {
 alert("Next, please enter your password")
}
else{
  reload();
}
</script>
<h1><script>
var passWord=prompt("Please enter your password:","Password")
if(passWord="person") {
 document.write("Welcome to headquarters, Person!")
}
else{
 reload();
}
</script></h1>
```

I am not sure how to make it work, because as of now, it always goes to the "welcome to headquarters" part. It never uses else, and it uses every username and password as right. I hope this makes sense and is possible. I would like to stick to this code as much as possible in the end since I wrote it from things I knew, not from a website. Thanks!  :)

Comment: Just to be sure, you're aware that this kind of username and password check is only useful for toy examples, right?

Comment: You are using `=` for comparison. To check if the `userName` is equal  to `"person"`, your code should look like `if(userName=="person") { // do this }`

Answer (score 2):

When comparing the password you had only one '='. This assigns a value. To compare, you need two ('==').

```html
<script>
alert("Welcome. Please click ok and enter your username.")
</script>
<script>
var userName=prompt("Please enter your username:","Username")
if(userName=="person") {
 alert("Next, please enter your password")
}
else{
  reload();
}
</script>
<h1><script>
var passWord=prompt("Please enter your password:","Password")
if(passWord=="person") {
 document.write("Welcome to headquarters, Person!")
}
else{
 reload();
}
</script></h1>
```

By the way, NEVER use this for production. Anyone can view the source and see the password in plain text.

Comment: Thank you so much, and I am only using it for personal, fun use, not commercial or on the internet.